# Debian stretch, executor failed running and some packages can not be authenticated

Tags: debian, postgresql

I have an error when I am building my Docker containers. It seems that there are problems with Postgres Stretch for Debian. I saw that Debian strech was removed and no longer supported.

```
W: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/11/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install dos2unix &&     apt-get clean' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I saw that Debian stretch is no longer supported so I assume that this caused this error.
In my docker postgresql file I changed to use domething newer, but I am still receiving following errors:

During installation of my docker image I am getting the following error:

```
#0 14.83 WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
#0 14.83   libgdbm3 libpopt0 libedit2 libgpm2 libkeyutils1 python-minimal mime-support
#0 14.83   libpython-stdlib python libisl10 libcloog-isl4 libmpdec2 libmpfr4 libxau6
#0 14.83   libxcb1 libxext6 libxmuu1 sgml-base libmpc3 ifupdown less manpages netbase
#0 14.83   libpsl0 python-support xz-utils binutils cpp gcc g++ make libtimedate-perl
#0 14.83   libdpkg-perl dpkg-dev build-essential python3-minimal libpython3-stdlib
#0 14.83   python3 dh-python libfakeroot fakeroot liberror-perl libalgorithm-c3-perl
#0 14.83   libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
#0 14.83   libarchive-extract-perl libcgi-pm-perl libfcgi-perl libcgi-fast-perl
#0 14.83   libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl libcpan-meta-perl libparams-util-perl
#0 14.83   libsub-install-perl libdata-optlist-perl libmro-compat-perl
#0 14.83   libsub-exporter-perl libdata-section-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl
#0 14.83   libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-c1 libgeos-dev liblog-message-perl
#0 14.83   liblog-message-simple-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl
#0 14.83   libpackage-constants-perl libpod-latex-perl libregexp-common-perl
#0 14.83   libpod-readme-perl libpython-dev libtext-template-perl
#0 14.83   libsoftware-license-perl libterm-ui-perl libtext-soundex-perl lsb-release
#0 14.83   manpages-dev python-ply python-pycparser python-cffi python-pkg-resources
#0 14.83   python-chardet python3-pkg-resources python-chardet-whl python-colorama
#0 14.83   python-colorama-whl python-six python-cryptography python-dev python-distlib
#0 14.83   python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-openssl
#0 14.83   python-ndg-httpsclient python-requests python-setuptools python-pip
#0 14.83   python-six-whl python-requests-whl python-setuptools-whl python-pip-whl
#0 14.83   python-pyasn1 python-virtualenv python-wheel python3-virtualenv rename
#0 14.83   virtualenv xauth xml-core
#0 14.83 E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y update     && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y upgrade     && apt-get -q -y install         python-dev         python-pip         python-virtualenv         python-wheel         libpq-dev         libxml2-dev         libxslt-dev         libgeos-dev         libssl-dev         libffi-dev         postgresql-client         build-essential         git-core         vim         wget     && apt-get -q clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
```

Here is my dockerfile for postgresql:

```
FROM FROM postgis11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install dos2unix && \
    apt-get clean

# Allow connections; we don't map out any ports so only linked docker containers can connect
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

# Customize default user/pass/db
ENV POSTGRES_DB test
ENV POSTGRES_USER test
ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD
ARG DS_RO_PASS

# Include datastore setup scripts
COPY ./postgresql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_create_datastore.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix
```

Can someone help me and let me know where to search and where the problem can be?

---

your suggestion to follow installation of how to make Docker work on Debian Stretch didn't worked. Anyway thanks for the link.
This solved just part of the problem, here is the error which I am receiving after the insallation:

```
     > [docker-db 2/5] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install dos2unix &&     apt-get clean:
#0 0.483 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [59.1 kB]
#0 0.485 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
#0 0.498 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [93.6 kB]
#0 0.524 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
#0 0.550 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [3,177 B]
#0 0.555 Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease
#0 0.589 Ign:7 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release
#0 0.611 Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [782 kB]
#0 0.622 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 0.656 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 0.693 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 0.725 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 0.758 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 0.790 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 0.800 Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7,080 kB]
#0 0.823 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 0.857 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 0.894 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 0.926 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 0.959 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 0.990 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 1.022 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 1.060 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 1.093 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 1.125 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 1.159 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 1.194 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 1.226 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 1.258 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 1.292 Err:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
#0 1.292   404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
#0 1.324 Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages
#0 1.357 Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main all Packages
#0 1.389 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 all Packages
#0 3.674 Fetched 8,135 kB in 3s (2,519 kB/s)
#0 3.674 Reading package lists...
#0 4.359 W: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 4.359 E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
#0 4.359 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install dos2unix &&     apt-get clean]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: 1/ use a brand new postgresql with stretch: not supported by upstream 2/ use Debian's provided postgresql with stretch: you might complain it's not recent enough. 3/ attempt some kind of FrankenDebian: fails . Solution: stop using stretch.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any possibility to use Debian stretch from the archives to have the application running? Even if is not supported anymore, I assume that thre should be the way how to access the archives? I know that this should be temporare solution and that using stretch is not the best way anymore.